# App not installed error in all devices in ionic 5 version?

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework

I have properly generated the release build in ionic 5 but its install in every device but i got “App not installed issue in every device” debugg APK is installed properly but issue in release build. i tried below solutions:

**Tried Solutions**

1. In AndroidManifest.xml under the application tag add **testOnly="false" and android:debuggable="true"
2. In AndroidManifest.xml under the application tag android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Can anynody help me how to fix above issue?

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue for android platform.

**Possibilty 1**

- Normally it happens when you try to install release .apk on the device(Mobile) where debug .apk is already installed.
  I recommend you should remove debug apk first and try to install release apk.

**Possibilty 2**

- Check if you have signed the release apk with the correct keystore.
- Get more idea about apk signing  here,

  https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Answer (score 0):

**After 2 days of struggle today i finally fixed my issue and i follow below procedure:**

1 – Build release unsigned apk.

2 – Zip align unsigned APK using the command prompt.

zipalign -v -p 4 my-app-unsigned.apk my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk
3 – Sign the APK with apsigner-

apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.keystore --out app-release.apk my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk

I am not using jarsigner command and becasue generated same issue then i will skip that cmd and follow above procedure.

Comment: so do you mean that apps built with the command option `--prod` woudn't work on real deive? I am facing the same issue. not able to install app on real device but i could install it on virtual device. tried `--prod` and `--prod --release` but both didn't work on real device